# SQL to provide current count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a log table that contains action records.  It looks something like this:

```
LogDate   LogTypeID JobID UserID
5/1/2014  1         12    5
5/2/2014  2         12    5
5/3/2014  1         13    5
5/6/2014  1         14    5
5/6/2014  3         14    5
5/7/2014  1         15    5
5/8/2014  2         15    5
5/9/2014  1         16    5
5/9/2014  2         16    5
```

For each job, there will always be a log entry for LogTypeID = 1.  This just means a job was sent to that user.  The same job could be sent to several users.  I want to keep a running total of how many jobs a user got that did NOT generate a logtypeid of 2 or 3.  In my case, it could be 2,4,7,8,10 for IDs as these are different job rejection codes.  The even trickier part is that if one job has a rejection but then the a job sent at a later date does NOT have any rejection, then the rejection count would be reset to 0.  Lastly, there are 2 different groups of rejection codes.  For group 1, there are logtypeids of 2,4,7,8,10) while group 2 has codes of 3,5,6,9.

Therefore, with the example data above, I want a way to return:

```
User ID   A-Rejects  B-Rejects
5         2          1
```

This result is because job 12 had a rejection but job 13 didn't do the total went back to 0.  Job 4 had a group B rejection while 15 and 16 each had a group 1 rejection.

Please note that the goal is to keep a running count per group where both group counts get reset if a job did not receive any rejections from either group.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You will need to demonstrate what you have tried.

Comment: So do I understand correctly: If there were another entry for May 9 JobID 12 and LogTypeID 1 fur UserID 5 then this would re-activate job 12 and make LogTypeID 2 of May 2 void? And what do you mean by running count? Do you want to have each users rejects on a daily basis? Or what else would be the "running" part if not days?

Comment: It looks like you want to group by UserID and JobID but you will have to better define your groups (A-Rejects, B-Rejects, "Group 1" rejection).  Job 14 has a rejection (3) but this isn't reflected in your example output.  Is A-Reject LogtypeID 1 and B-Reject LogTypeID 3?

Comment: At second glance it looks like "Job 4" should be "Job 14" and "Group 1"  should be "Group A" - is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to see what you have so far?  If I understand the question, reporting on what doesn't exist can be tricky sometimes.

But for example, this may be as simple as running a SUM like so,

```
SELECT SUM(IIF(LOGTYPEID in (2,3), 0, 1) as Total FROM LOGTABLE
```

Comment: Not every SQL Server implementation has access to IIF. It's probably better to actually spell out the CASE expression.

Comment: Ah I didn't know they didn't add that till recently, I've been using it in TSQL Access since before SQL 2008 so not sure why they didn't implement it sooner, but I like the brevity.  Another poster took care of the CASE version.

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the problem is a bit confusing 
but I'd start with something like this. Which will count up the totals of the three different sorts of log entry per job/

```
SELECT 
UserID, JobID,
SUM (CASE WHEN LogTypeID = 1 then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LogType1,
SUM (CASE WHEN LogTypeID IN (2,4,7,8,10) then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [A-REjects],
SUM (CASE WHEN LogTypeID IN (3,5,6,9) then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [B-REjects]
FROM [TableName]
GROUP BY  UserID, JobID
```

(You can use the IIF syntax suggested in Jimmy Smith's answer if you want)

You can then use that as a subquery to count the jobs where those totals match whatever criteria you choose

```
SELECT 
t.UserID,
SUM(CASE WHEN t.LogType1 > 1 AND t.[A-REjects] = 0 AND t.[B-REjects] = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LogType1Only,
SUM(CASE WHEN t.LogType1 = 0 AND t.[A-REjects] > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [A-REjects] ,
SUM(CASE WHEN t.LogType1 = 0 AND t.[B-REjects] > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [B-REjects] 
FROM 
(
SELECT 
UserID, JobID,
SUM (CASE WHEN LogTypeID = 1 then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LogType1,
SUM (CASE WHEN LogTypeID IN (2,4,7,8,10) then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [A-REjects],
SUM (CASE WHEN LogTypeID IN (3,5,6,9) then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [B-REjects]
FROM [TableName]
GROUP BY  UserID, JobID
) t
GROUP BY UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think this will take into account the resetting if one job is successful.

```
With Reset_Points as (
Select L.UserID
    , MAX(L.LogDate) as LogDate

From LogTable L
    Left Outer Join LogTable L_R1 --1st Portion of Reset Logic
        on L.UserID = L_R1.UserID
            and L.JobID = L_R1.JobID
            and L.LogTypeID = 1
    Left Outer Join LogTable L_R2 --2nd Portion of Reset Logic
        on L_R1.UserID = L_R2.UserID
            and L_R1.JobID = L_R2.JobID
            and L_R2.LogTypeID <> 1

Where L_R1.UserID is not null
    and L_R2.UserID is null

Group by L.UserID
)

, Distinct_Records as (
Select Distinct L.*
    , Case When L_A.UserID is null Then 0 Else 1 End as A_Reject
    , Case When L_B.UserID is null Then 0 Else 1 End as B_Reject

From LogTable L
    Left Outer Join Reset_Points R
        on L.UserID = R.UserID
    Left Outer Join LogTable L_A --Group A Rejects
        on L.UserID = L_A.UserID
            and L.JobID = L_A.JobID
            and L_A.LogDate > R.LogDate
            and L.LogTypeID in(2,4,7,8,10)
    Left Outer Join LogTable L_B --Group B Rejects
        on L.UserID = L_B.UserID
            and L.JobID = L_B.JobID
            and L_B.LogDate > R.LogDate
            and L.LogTypeID in(3,5,6,9)
)

Select UserID
    , SUM(A_Reject) as A_Rejects
    , SUM(B_Reject) as B_Rejects

From Distinct_Records

Group by UserID
```

Note that if you have some sort of distinct row identifier, you can get rid of the Distinct_Records CTE and just directly count distinct row identifiers in the L_A and L_B tables, like this:

```
With Reset_Points as (
Select L.UserID
    , MAX(L.LogDate) as LogDate

From LogTable L
    Left Outer Join LogTable L_R1 --1st Portion of Reset Logic
        on L.UserID = L_R1.UserID
            and L.JobID = L_R1.JobID
            and L.LogTypeID = 1
    Left Outer Join LogTable L_R2 --2nd Portion of Reset Logic
        on L_R1.UserID = L_R2.UserID
            and L_R1.JobID = L_R2.JobID
            and L_R2.LogTypeID <> 1

Where L_R1.UserID is not null
    and L_R2.UserID is null

Group by L.UserID
)

Select L.UserID
    , COUNT(Distinct L_A.RowID) as A_Reject
    , COUNT(Distinct L_B.RowID) as B_Reject

From LogTable L
    Left Outer Join Reset_Points R
        on L.UserID = R.UserID
    Left Outer Join LogTable L_A --Group A Rejects
        on L.UserID = L_A.UserID
            and L.JobID = L_A.JobID
            and L_A.LogDate > R.LogDate
            and L.LogTypeID in(2,4,7,8,10)
    Left Outer Join LogTable L_B --Group B Rejects
        on L.UserID = L_B.UserID
            and L.JobID = L_B.JobID
            and L_B.LogDate > R.LogDate
            and L.LogTypeID in(3,5,6,9)

Group by L.UserID
```